# Shouldn't using break in the inner loop of the following code makes more sense?

Tags: java, algorithm

I'm trying to solve a problem called **fix34**. It expects to return an array that contains exactly the same numbers as the given array, but rearranged so that every 3 is immediately followed by a 4. Do not move the 3's, but every other number may move. The array contains the same number of 3's and 4's, every 3 has a number after it that is not a 3, and a 3 appears in the array before any 4.

I came up with the following code:

```
public int[] fix34(int[] nums) {
    for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++)
        if (nums[i] == 3) {
            int temp = nums[i + 1];
            nums[i + 1] = 4;
            for (int j = i + 2; j < nums.length; j++){
                if (nums[j] == 4) nums[j] = temp;
                break;
            }
        }
    return nums;
}
```

now, the problem is that if I don't use that **break** in the inner loop, It passes all the tests, otherwise not!! To me, using that makes more sense because the inner loop might end up replacing all 4's with the **temp**.

Please clarify why am I wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Please tag your question with the language you are using.

Comment: If your code already works, then this question might be better suited to [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 2):

The reason is that your `break` currently gets executed on the first iteration of the second for loop. If you don't add curly braces after an `if(condition)` statement, only the first line after that is executed if the condition is true:

```
if (nums[j] == 4) nums[j] = temp; // Only this gets executed if the condition is true
break; // the condition has no effect on this statement
```

Since you only want to `break` if the condition is met you should do:

```
if (nums[j] == 4) {
    nums[j] = temp;
    break;
}
```

As a sidenote, you can also solve this problem more efficiently with just a single iteration. See @dasblinkenlight's answer for that.

**Edit**:
Okay, I've looked at the problem a little closer and realized the problem is that your version doesn't even actually work when you omit the `break`. The fact that it passes all tests on codingBat is a pure coincidence.

As you've stated yourself correctly, not having the `break` may cause the loop to overwrite too many array entries with the `temp` variable, and this is exactly what is happening in this case. It just happens to be the correct value for the given test cases, which makes it look like the code is correct.

The reason why the code doesn't work if you just add a `break` even though it should on first sight is this: The problem only states that there is no `4` before the first `3`. It doesn't say that there will be only one `4` between two `3`s. This means that you can't just start at `j = i + 2` to search for the `4` to replace, because it might actually be before `i`.

I've written a solution in a different approach than the one proposed by @dasblinkenlight (because I didn't just want to copy his algorithm). My version loops over the array twice, which still means it's O(n):

```
public int[] fix34(int[] nums) {
    int[] result = new int[nums.length];
    ArrayList otherNumbers = new ArrayList();
    for(int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++){
        if(nums[i] == 3) {
            result[i] = 3;
            result[i+1] = 4;
        } else if(nums[i] != 4) {
            otherNumbers.add(nums[i]);
        }
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
        if(result[i] != 3 && result[i] != 4)
            result[i] = (Integer)otherNumbers.remove(0);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Hi, It still doesn't pass all the test after adding the braces for **if**.

Comment: Thank you. Could you please recommend me some books/websites which could improve my logic or algorithmic capability? My logic is quite weak and I hardly come up with Brute force solution of a problem. Thank you in advance. :-)

Answer (score 2):

This can be solved with a single loop:

- Go through the array right to left. Since you are going backward, you will see enough fours before each three.
- Maintain a reading index and a writing index.
- Whenever you see a four at the reading index, skip ahead to an earlier index
- Whenever you see a three, write a four, advance the writing index, and then write a three
- Any other number gets copied as-is

At the end of the loop, the array will be re-arranged as needed.

```
int[] data = new int[] {1, 2, 3, 5, 5, 4, 3, 7, 3, 4, 2, 3, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4};
// Expected:            1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 3, 4, 7, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4
int r = data.length-1;
int w = data.length-1;
while (r >= 0) {
    switch(data[r]) {
        case 3:
            data[w--] = 4;
            data[w--] = 3;
        case 4:
            break;
        default:
            data[w--] = data[r];
            break;
    }
    r--;
}
for (int i = 0 ; i != data.length ; i++) {
    System.out.print(data[i]+" ");
}
System.out.println();
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/iGN7nO)

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm beginner so can't turn that into the code. Could you please provide the code for the same?

Comment: Also, could you please recommend me some book/website or anything else to improve my logic ability?

Comment: @AnandTyagi The conversion is really straightforward - in this case, `switch` fits the requirement very well, because you have two specific constants + everything else. As far as web sites are concerned, there is no exercise I know to help you develop the skill. However, if you manage to work through [a really old article by Dijkstra](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/EWD/ewd02xx/EWD249.PDF) you would see construction of algorithms from a different perspective that is rarely taught these days.